# How to generate a single dll from two C# projects? C# DLL COM + C# DLL

Tags: c#, assemblies

**My First project, type class library:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Project2
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int num = 33;
    }
}
```

with the command line `sn -k keyPair.snk` I generate a keypair and I added keypair.snk to sign.

**Second project type class library:**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using Project2;

namespace CSharpServer
{
   [ComVisible(true)]
   [Guid("DBE0E8C4-1C61-41f3-B6A4-4E2F353D3D05")]
   public interface IManagedInterface
   {
      int PrintHi();
   }

   [ComVisible(true)]
   [Guid("C6659361-1625-4746-931C-36014B146679")]
   public class InterfaceImplementation : IManagedInterface
   {
      public int PrintHi()
      {
         Class1 obj = new Class1(); // Using first project
         return obj.num; // return public int num = 33;
      }
   }
}
```

I added keypair.snk to sign.

to Use "using Project2;" in project CSharpServer I clicked "Add/Existing Project.." Project2.csproj after this I clicked in "Add Reference../Projects".

When I compiled, Generates two dlls, **how to generate a single dll with the two projects?**

I read about ILMerge. It seems that it combines two dll. But I have the source code, would not have a way to do this join in Visual Studio?

I read [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mergingassemblies.aspx) that says "you can obviously just add all source files to a single project" but if my first project has 1000 classes?

I tried ilmerge:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ILMerge\ilmerge" /target:library /out:project.dll CSharpServer.dll Project2.dll

generate one file project.dll

Problems:
if i do: regasm project.dll /tlb /codebase

> ...
>       RegAsm : warning RA0000 : Registering an unsigned assembly with
>   /codebase can ca
>       use your assembly to interfere with other applications that may be
>   installed on
>       the same computer. The /codebase switch is intended to be used only
>   with signed
>       assemblies. Please give your assembly a strong name and re-register
>   it.
>       Types registered successfully ...

How to sign this merged dll?
CSharpServer.dll is Component COM with interface and need to be registered with regasm. Project2.dll not need.
Detail,
I only want to register CSharpServer.dll but the project.dll contains (CSharpServer.dll + Project2.dll). And now?

I tried to sign: `sn -R project.dll keyPair.snk`. Output:

> Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility  Version 2.0.50727.42
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> project.dll does not represent a strongly named assembly

The sign works with:
To sign, have to extract the public key:
`sn -p keyPair.snk publickey.snk`

I read it [Giving a .NET SN](http://www.developer.com/net/vb/article.php/3292231/Giving-a-NET-Assembly-a-Strong-Name.htm)

specifying and matching public key:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ILMerge\ilmerge" /keyfile:publickey.snk /target:library /out:project.dll CSharpServer.dll Project2.dll

After signing with the command:
`sn -R project.dll keyPair.snk`

Now the question is:
Register this dll combined with regasm. It's like regasm only interface? what impact it?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Why don't you just make a single project?

Comment: I am simulating the use of a library for a C# COM component. So I can not put in the same project.

Comment: The message you get from regasm.exe is just a warning.  It means: "you're about to invoke DLL Hell, are you sure?".  You are on your dev machine.  You'll have to sign the merged assembly by hand, after running ilmerge.  Use sn.exe.  That the merged assembly contains classes from project2.dll and that you now have 1001 classes instead of a 1000 in an assembly is not relevant.  Be sure to use [ComVisible] explicitly on each interface you want to make visible.

Comment: Are you saying, when I try to register only the interface Visible is registered? if i do regasm project.dll (CSharpServer.dll + Project2.dll), Is the same thing if I do regasm CSharpServer.dll because Project2.dll does not have interface?

Comment: @Hans Passant. I tried to sign: sn -R project.dll keyPair.snk. Output: project.dll does not represent a strongly named assembly.

Comment: Ah, right, you have to use the /keyfile option with ILMerge.

Comment: @Hans Passant. Thanks, this works. sn -p keyPair.snk publickey.snk. /keyfile:publickey.snk in iLMerg. Than sn -R project.dll keyPair.snk. Register this dll combined with regasm. It's like regasm only interface?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do that by compiling the code using `csc.exe` outside visual studio and passing the command-line parameters yourself (all `.cs` files).

This will be a bit tedious but can be done. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx).

Comment: I'll try to do it, but "for all. Cs files". seems strange

Comment: if one of my projects have more than 1000 classes? Is there any simpler way to do this?

Comment: Thanks.
I try to combine using ilmerge, but I'm having problems with the signing of the dll.

Comment: To ease the pain of adding references to all of your cs files, you could use Powershell to iterate over your project directories and build up the arguments in a string variable, then execute csc from your powershell script, providing that string as your arguments.

Comment: @hermiod Is there a exemple to use Powershell to iterate using visual studio? Have I to edit pre-build?

Comment: Try this link: http://davidfrette.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/creating-powershell-pre-build-and-post-build-events-for-visual-studio-projects/

Comment: @hermiod thanks. is a bit complex to do this script. ILMerge I think I'll use it. With him I do not need to recompile the library, only to merge the dlls. I wonder if I make regasm on "dll combined". I wonder what happens. I did the test here and it worked, I could use the dll, but I do not know what impact it. Thanks again.