# Create a single "dll" starting from two independent projects (same solution)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll, .net-assembly

I have a small solution with 2 projects "Class Library" independent, ie, no project is used as a reference in another.

The first project is called "Extension1" and the second "extension2". I would not want to use this solution in another project and having to reference the two dlls separately, I need to create a single dll "CustomExtension.dll" and that it has the two ("Extension1.dll" and "Extension2.dll") to reference only dll "CustomExtension.dll" on a new project using only the respective namespace. Is this possible?

PS: Windows 8 - Visual Studio 2010 Professional - C#

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2008: Creating Single DLL from Solution with Many Projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878807/visual-studio-2008-creating-single-dll-from-solution-with-many-projects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might want to take a look at ILMerge. We use it in a lot of our projects for combining multiple dll's into one.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630

Comment: Thank you all!
1 - I added ILMerge through the "Manage Nuget Packages"
2 - I inserted the command "Post-build event command line:"
3 - I got the command line at link "http://elemarjr.net/2010/09/03/o-mistrio-da-referncia-para-uma-dll-oculta-ilmerge/"

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this could be a very tedious task. Take a look at this answer to a previous question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6573711/329928

> You have to do that by compiling the code using csc.exe outside visual
>   studio and passing the command-line parameters yourself (all .cs
>   files).
>
> This will be a bit tedious but can be done. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx

Comment: Haha. Don't blame me. I'm just the messenger. :)

Comment: Sorry my english! I am Brazilian and I'm still learning, actually wanted to thank you! ;)

Comment: No problem. I was just being stupid. :) I am glad you were able to figure out how to create the one DLL.